Row inside a Column Widget
I am using a Gridview inside that gridview i am using Column and Some text after that a Row for some buttons but i want the alignment from left side of button and text would be same so it looks nice UI but row is giving unusual space from left so it does match the text alignment and buttons looks uneven
i tried expanded and stack but that space is still there and the alignment from left is not matching enter image description here

Welcome to SO! Can you please share some code?

Since you haven't shared any code I can only guess.
I assume you are using a Button widget. These widgets come with minimum touch target sizes, which likely is the reason why you are experiencing the undesired space to the left.
If you want to remove this touch target you can update the MaterialTapTargetSize (docs here) from using .padded to .shrinkWrap.

Instead of using a Column and Row widget, I assume you can just use the GridView class to create the UI you want (which is 2 columns and n rows). You would set the crossAxisCount to 2. Check this link to read more.
Also, making a custom widget for the fruit options might make it easier for the UI to look more consistent.
Furthermore, you have pixels overflowing. Please share the specific error message and your code if possible.

Great, glad I could help. If you could, please accept an answer so it is easier for others to see what worked. Also, could you please put your code in your answer in a code block. This will help with readability

I got the way to do this:
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
      Text(
      _gridItems[index].name,
      style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
       ),
      const SizedBox(height: 2),
  Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0), 
  child: Transform.translate(
    offset: const Offset(-20, 0), 
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
       ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
          ),
          onPressed: () => _increaseQuantity(_gridItems[index].name),
          child: const Text(
            '-',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
      
        Text(
          '${_quantity} KG',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
      
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
          ),
          onPressed: () => _increaseQuantity(_gridItems[index].name),
          child: const Text(
            '+',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
